# How can I load a main css/scss file from a gitlab repo and have it load last within my vue project?

Tags: css, vue.js, gitlab, vuetify.js, vue-cli

**I have a gitlab repo which contains a master css/scss file I'd like to import into my vue project, but after everything else has loaded**. For example, I am also using vuetify in my project and would like my css file to load after this as well to account for my adjustments to overwrite some vuetify css. Reason I want to do this is to have one main css file for future components or projects so I dont have to recreate it over and over, and can just import one main file. Can this be done, or am I not approaching this correctly? Any feedback or direction to some documentation would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: https://gomakethings.com/how-to-turn-any-github-repo-into-a-cdn/

Comment: YESSSS! Thank you